# Dot Net Nuke site landing page loading more time for the first time

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-5, dnn9

DNN site taking more time to load landing page for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide a lot of information about your problem (Which DNN/IIS/Windows version?) I can only guess what you really mean. But most propably it is the behaviour of the IIS AppPool that shuts down after a while when no one visits the site or the server has been restarted or the AppPool is recycled.

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155007/creating-a-local-keep-alive-service-on-your-web-server) a while ago how to fix it, but that was for IIS 7 (and before), please read also the comments which point out a more accurate way to get rid of this problem since IIS 8.